# How to search multiple values in two columns in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which looks like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable mt
WHERE 1=1
AND mt.column_1 IN (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE salary >10000)
OR  mt.column_2 IN (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE salary >10000)
```

I know the above query is not looking good even though it is getting my job done. I did google but could not find help. The reason I ask is the actual scenario the 'employee' table is temp table which is filled with data at the upper levels of the strored_procedure and this particular is my final select statement for the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple `JOIN` would do the trick

```
SELECT mt.* 
 FROM mytable mt
 JOIN (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE salary >10000) B
   on mt.column_1=B.ID or mt.column_2=B.ID
```